# Find and unarchive Ansible module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How to fix the below Ansible task to `find` the file and `unarchive`.

```
- name: find the file
  find:
    paths: /home/ec2-user/aa/
    pattern: "file-*.tar.gz"
  register: copied_file

- name: extract  the file
  unarchive:
     src: /home/ec2-user/aa/"{{ item }}"
     dest: /home/ec2-user/bb/
  with_fileglob:
      - "{{ copied_file.files }}"
```

I am facing this error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the error, and a sample output of `copied_file` variable? Also, there seems to be an extraneous space in `aa/ "{{ item }}`.

Comment: I have updated the error in the question. And removed the extra space still the same error

Comment: The extra space `src: /home/ec2-user/aa/ "{{ item }}"` seems to be still there. You may change the source to `"/home/ec2-user/aa/{{ item }}"` or `/home/ec2-user/aa/{{ item }}`.

Comment: Can you update the question with an output of `copied_file` variable?

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up different data structures. The result in `copied_file.files` does not contain a file name only. The `unarchive` with `with_fileglob` can't work because of that reason too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `list' object has no attribute 'rfind'`

There is a data structure mismatch in your case.

```
- name: Find file
  find:
    paths: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
    pattern: "*.tar.gz"
  register: result
```

The Ansible [find_module will return as value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#return-values) not only the filename, but a list. It will then be necessary to loop over it to get the file path.

```
- name: Show result file path
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.path }}"
  loop: "{{ result.files }}"
```

Therefore might for work for you

```
- name: Extract file
  unarchive:
    src: {{ item.path }}
    dest: /home/{{ ansible_user }}/extracted/
  loop: {{ result.files }}
```

Comment: How can i use the COPY module instead of FIND module?